# How to get name of tableid of an existing Dataset in Cloud Bigquery

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Currently, I am implemting our project for inserting data from cloud storage into Bigquery. About the way to insert. Please refer the link below is the way which I do
[How to load data from Cloud Storage into BigQuery using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259394/how-to-load-data-from-cloud-storage-into-bigquery-using-java)
However, I want to check the existing name of table in dataset in Bigquery before inserting data into bigquery.
I will be very happy if you can share your idea in solving this case ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

```
private static void listTables(Bigquery service, String projectNumber, String datasetId) throws IOException {

    Bigquery.Tables.List listTablesReply = service.tables().list(projectNumber, datasetId);
    TableList tableList = listTablesReply.execute();

    if (tableList.getTables() != null) {

      List tables = tableList.getTables();

      System.out.println("Tables list:");

      for (TableList.Tables table : tables) {
         System.out.format("%s\n", table.getId());
      }
    }
}
```

I think it will be help us in this case :)

Comment: The helpful link for manage table :https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#browsingtabledata