# Uploading JSON files into BigQuery from local drive using Java

Tags: java, json, google-bigquery

Hi
I am new to Google BigQuery.
Searching for sample JAVA code which will pick up JSON files from my local drive and will upload into BigQuery. In this process the code should:

1. read from file in local drive containing JSON data newline separated
2. generate a new table in the BigQuery
3. generate table schema reading the JSON from the file realtime
4. upload it into the BigQuery table newly generated.

Any help will be a leap for me. Pls let me know if my requirement is clear here!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these:

- [Getting Started with BigQuery and the Google Java API Client library](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/gettingstartedwithjava)
- [A sample Java application that accesses the BigQuery API](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-getting-started-java)
- [Streaming Data Into BigQuery](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaminginsertexamples) (Java code at the bottom)
- [How to load data from Cloud Storage into BigQuery using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259394/how-to-load-data-from-cloud-storage-into-bigquery-using-java)
- [questions tagged with google-bigquery + java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-bigquery+java?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50)

Answer (score 1):

```
public long writeJSONFileToTable(String datasetName, String tableName, Path JSONPath, String location)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
      LoadStatistics stats = null;
      try {
            //[START bigquery_load_from_file]
            TableId tableId = TableId.of(datasetName, tableName);
            //WriteChannelConfiguration writeChannelConfiguration = WriteChannelConfiguration.newBuilder(tableId).setFormatOptions(FormatOptions.csv()).build();
            WriteChannelConfiguration writeChannelConfiguration = WriteChannelConfiguration.newBuilder(tableId).setFormatOptions(FormatOptions.json()).build();
            // The location must be specified; other fields can be auto-detected.
            JobId jobId = JobId.newBuilder().setLocation(location).build();
            TableDataWriteChannel writer = bigquery.writer(jobId, writeChannelConfiguration);

            // Write data to writer
            try (OutputStream stream = Channels.newOutputStream(writer)) {
              Files.copy(JSONPath, stream);
            }
            // Get load job
            Job job = writer.getJob();
            job = job.waitFor();
            stats = job.getStatistics();
            System.out.println("State: " + job.getStatus().getState());
            System.out.println(stats.getOutputRows());

            // [END bigquery_load_from_file]
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception           
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      return stats.getOutputRows();    
  }
```

Comment: To read the JSON file => Path JSONpath = Paths.get("--------------------/data.json");            The JSON file contains one object should be in one line. don't enclose in array braces. eg {"id": 1,"name": "bigquery"}.